# What are the differences between a GD and a GD2 image?

Tags: php, gd, gd2

Reading the documentation for [imagegd2()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegd2.php), and [imagegd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegd.php), I noticed the functions are described, respectively as:

- Output GD2 image to browser or file
- Output GD image to browser or file

What are a GD2, and a GD image? What are the difference between those image types?

Comment: Where do you see them as being different?

Comment: In php.net I saw two functions

imagegd2 :- Output GD2 image to browser or file

imagegd — Output GD image to browser or file

So I asked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gd is an old c library, gd2 is the updated one. php uses gd2.

Comment: Are there any bc breaks?

Comment: @JosefSábl, GD has been phased out more than 6 years ago; the question of backward compatibility is no longer relevant.

Comment: I'm using laravel. but In it, Image Driver is gd. Isn't it gd2?

Answer (score 1):

Some version of GD generates only PNG, but recent version can ganerate GIF and PNG. Soon GD 1 [will be no longer supported](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/removal-of-deprecated-features) in next version of PHP.

Comment: "Soon GD will be no longer supported in next version of PHP." please add a reference/link to support this claim?

Comment: Here it is : http://wiki.php.net/rfc/removal-of-deprecated-features

Support for Freetype 1 and GD 1 - See R197385, R197386, R203752 and family commits

Comment: GD 1 will no longer be supported. That makes sense. GD2 support will stay.